# Returning the size of a polymorphic binary search tree in Java?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a size() method for a polymorphic binary search tree. 
I.e. A BST that has classes EmptyTree and NonEmptyTree that both implement a "tree" interface. EmptyTree is being used to represent an empty tree or subtree instead of null (like in a regular BST)

```
public interface Tree<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {
    public int size();
    public NonEmptyTree<K, V> add(K key, V value);

    //bunch of other methods
}
```

I've made both EmptyTree and NonEmptyTree implement the size() method from the Tree interface like so:

```
public int size() { //in EmptyTree class
   return 0;
}

public int size() { //in NonEmptyTree class
   return 1 + left.size() + right.size();
}
```

However, when I try to run this in a test:

```
Tree<Integer, String> treeThree = EmptyTree.getInstance(); //EmptyTree is a singleton class
   treeThree = treeThree.add(3, "3"); 
   treeThree = treeThree.add(2, "2"); 
   treeThree = treeThree.add(1, "1"); 
   treeThree = treeThree.add(4, "4");
   assertEquals(4, treeThree.size());
```

It says that the size of treeThree is 3, rather than 4 like it should be.

It works just fine for these ones though:

```
        Tree<Integer, String> empty = EmptyTree.getInstance();
        assertEquals(0, empty.size());

        Tree<Integer, String> treeOne = EmptyTree.getInstance();
        treeOne = treeOne.add(2, "2"); treeOne = treeOne.add(1, "1"); treeOne = treeOne.add(3, "3");
        assertEquals(3, treeOne.size());

        Tree<Integer, String> treeTwo = EmptyTree.getInstance();
        treeTwo = treeTwo.add(3, "3"); treeTwo = treeTwo.add(2, "2");
        assertEquals(2, treeTwo.size());
```

EmptyTree add method:

```
public NonEmptyTree<K, V> add(K key, V value) {  
    return new NonEmptyTree(key, value);
}
```

NonEmptyTree add method:

```
public NonEmptyTree<K, V> add(K key, V value) {
      if(this.key.compareTo(key) == 0) {
          this.value = value;
          return this;
      }
      else {
          if(key.compareTo(this.key) < 0) { 
              if(this.left.lookup(key) == null) {
                  this.left = new NonEmptyTree<K,V>(key, value);
                  return this;
              }
              else
                  return this.left.add(key, value);
          }
          else if(key.compareTo(this.key) > 0) { 
              if(this.right.lookup(key) == null) {
                  this.right = new NonEmptyTree<K,V>(key, value);
                  return this;
              }
              else
                  return this.right.add(key, value);
          }
      }
      return this;
  }
```

EmptyTree lookup:

```
public V lookup(K key) {
    return null;
  }
```

NonEmptyTree lookup:

```
public V lookup(K key) {
      if(key.compareTo(this.key) == 0)
          return this.value;
      else {
          if(key.compareTo(this.key) < 0)
              return this.left.lookup(key);
          if(key.compareTo(this.key) > 0) 
              return this.right.lookup(key);
      }

    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Is that the smallest example for which it fails?  In any case, how does `treeThree` change its class from `EmptyTree` to `NonEmptyTree` after the first element is added to it?  I don't understand how polymorphism could work here, unless a class object is allowed to change its class in Java.

Comment: I added a few other examples that worked

Comment: Whoops, I missed that you were assigning the result of calling `add()` back to `treeThree`, so that makes sense now.  Does `lookup()` return just the value *at* that node?  It should.  (And BTW: the fact that you write `this.left.lookup(key) == null` suggests that having the `EmptyTree` type isn't so useful after all, doesn't it.)

Comment: Added the lookup methods

Comment: Ah, the problem is with the fact that you call `lookup()` while trying to add node.  Suppose you're adding an element, and `if(key.compareTo(this.key) < 0)` in `NonEmptyTree.add()` has just succeeded.  Suppose further that the current node has a left subtree containing k > 0 nodes, but that `key` does not appear among them: then `lookup()` will return `false`, and you will discard the entire existing subtree rooted at the left child and replace it with the single new `key`-containing node when you call `this.left = new NonEmptyTree<K,V>(key, value);`.

Comment: Solution: You don't need to call `lookup()` during `add()`, and in fact you must not.  All you need to do is check whether the left or right child is a `NonEmptyTree` or not.  If it is, then just recursively call `add()` on it, and you're done.  You should only assign the new node directly if the child node is an `EmptyTreeNode`.

Comment: If the size of a non-empty tree is 1+left.size()+right.size(), the size of an empty tree must be 1, not 0. I don't see any need for the EmptyTree class whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

As Mr. j_random_hacker said in comment, you don't need to call look up method in your add method. That replaces the entire subtree that contains EmptyTree as it's children.
Change your add method as this,

```
public NonEmptyTree<K, V> add(K key, V value) {
      if(this.key.compareTo(key) == 0) {
          this.value = value;
      }
      else {
          if(key.compareTo(this.key) < 0) { 
                  this.left = this.left.add(key, value);
          }
          else { 
                  this.right = this.right.add(key, value);
          }
      }
      return this;
  }
```

Comment: The instance variables, key and value are originally set to null, so I am getting null pointer exceptions. They have to be set to null because we don't know what is going to be entered in.